# R remote execution

Tags: r, deployment

I have following work flow. A have an application A, which I have to run in different settings.

Currently, I define vectors X, Y, and Z in my R script. Then, I use expand.grid to produce a matrix. Each row in a matrix represents a distinct setting, which I convert into the list of input parameters.

Application A is started with these parameters, the script waits until the application finishes. Finally script collects necessary data and starts the application in a new setting.

At the moment I'm able to run single instance of the application at a time. I want to improve this in a following way. First, I want to be able to start several instances of the application at once, because I have multicore CPU and application is single threaded. Second, I have several remote machines, which I want to use with the same purpose.

Could you advise me how can I do this in R?

I heard about fabric library in pythion (http://www.fabfile.org/). I think it provides what I want. Is there something similar in R?

Answer (score 1):

You want to read the **excellent** vignette [Package: parallel](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) about the package of the same name *which also came with your version of R*.  It will teach you all you need to know about multi-core processing on one box.

For launching jobs on several computers, consider the [JSS survey paper on high-performance and parallel computing with R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i01/paper) and/or see the [CRAN Task View on High-Performance Computing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html)

*Disclosure: I am a co-author on the paper, and the current/founding editor of that Task View.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the thing is that I use this R script to run external application. And I remember I had troubles trying to run the application using parRapply. Could you acknowledge that function system2 inside parRapply is supposed to work?

Comment: "I had troubles" lacks details. *If* you have application installed *and* have it in the `$PATH` then `system("nameofapp")` will run it, ditto for `system2()`.  Well, and if you don't, then you got to figure where your setup fell short.

Comment: "I had troubles" I understand. I just can't reproduce the setup right now. But if you expect no problem, then I will try again.